# Does ios6 have any APIs that allow you to interact with the phone other than send numbers to dial?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

I know that you cannot delete the apple pre-installed apps on the iPhone unless it is jail broken.  My question revolves around the actual phone app that sends/ receives calls.  Does ios6 have any APIs that allow you to interact with the phone other than send numbers to dial?  Is there a way to have an app intercept incoming call details?

Comment: there's nothing in the official SDK or API's, as Apple would consider this a hard core security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way with which you can access call details. Since calls is itself an application and in iOS you cannot access other app's data from your app.